# How to efficient perform column wise multiply?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to apply multiple multiplication columns wise in data.table. Example:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=1:5,b=2:6,c=3:7,
                 d=rep(1,5),e=rep(0,5),f=rep(-1,5))
```

I want the results of a * d, b * e, and c * f, because I have 400 columns multiply another 400 column,
I wonder if there are some efficient solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply one set of columns by the other:

```
> DT[,1:3]*DT[,4:6]
   a b  c
1: 1 0 -3
2: 2 0 -4
3: 3 0 -5
4: 4 0 -6
5: 5 0 -7
```

For your larger problem, with 800 columns, it should just be:

```
> DT[,1:400]*DT[,401:800]
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if this can be done via colnames and and attach to the original data.table ?

Comment: @user1730977 `DT[, (new_names) := DT[,1:400]*DT[,401:800]]` works, where you fill in the new_names object. This is a pretty nonstandard thing to do in data.table, though, I reckon. And yeah, you can type col names in place of the 1:400 and 401:800.

Answer (score 0):

yeah,it's quite easy,but I confused so long!

```
DT[,paste0("a",1:3):= DT[,1:3]*DT[,4:6]]
```

Comment: Why not just accept the other answer instead of posting your own.  He did give you your answer.  You didn't mention anything about adding new columns in the question.

Comment: Sorry! It is my first question and with Spacedman's answer I realized how to do it. Thanks remind me!

Answer (score -1):

Another approach:

```
    DT[, Reduce('*',list(DT[,c("a","b","c")],DT[,c("d","e","f")]))]
```